# Show / Hide / Toggle - Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new with Javascript.

I'm trying to do something with Show/Hide functions.

html:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>

<style>
#button01 {
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 margin:10px;
 padding:6px 0 0 0;
 background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

#button01:hover {
 background-color:#ffcccc;
}

#button01 a {
 display:block;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 margin:auto;
 background:url("button01.png")
}

#button01 a:hover {
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 background:url("button01-hover.png")
}

#hidden01 {
 display:none;
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 margin:0 0 10px 0;
 border:4px solid #ffcccc;
}

#button02 {
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 margin:10px;
 padding:6px 0 0 0;
 background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

#button02:hover {
 background-color:#cccccc;
}

#button02 a {
 display:block;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 margin:auto;
 background:url("button02.png")
}

#button02 a:hover {
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 background:url("button02-hover.png")
}

#hidden02 {
 display:none;
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 margin:0 0 10px 0;
 border:4px solid #cccccc;
}
</style>




 </head>

 <body>



<div style="width:300px;">
<div id="button01"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(0);return false"></a></div>


<div id="button02"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(1);return false"></a></div>
</div>

<div id="hidden01">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="hidden02">&nbsp;</div>


 </body>
</html>
```

script:

```
        function toggle(offset){
            var i, x;
            var stuff = Array('hidden01', 'hidden02');  //put all the id's of the divs here in order 
            for (i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++){  //hide all the divs
                  x = document.getElementById(stuff[i]);
                  x.style.display = "none";
            }
            // now make the target div visible
            x = document.getElementById(stuff[offset]);
            x.style.display = "block";
         window.onload = function(){toggle(0);}
        }
```

That's working, but I want to fix 2 things:

1- Close/Hide hidden divs if I click on it's corresponding button;

2- After clicking a button, fix hover button image. If click again unfix;

I've tried almost all the scripts posted and can not find a solution. I don't want to open the divs at same time.
If opens one, close the others.

Comment: Less JavaScript, more jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery, so **use jQuery.**

```
$(function() {

    function toggle(offset) {
        $('div[id^=hidden]').hide().eq(offset).show();
    }

    toggle(0);
});
```

I don't know what you mean by the two things you want to fix, however. Please clarify.

---

### Edit

Okay, I see what you're going for now. I've cleaned up your code a lot.

#### HTML

```
<div style="width:300px;">
    <div id="button1"><a></a></div>
    <div id="button2"><a></a></div>
</div>

<div id="hidden1">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="hidden2">&nbsp;</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#button1, #button2 {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:6px 0 0 0;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

#button1:hover {
    background-color:#fcc;
}

#button2:hover {
    background-color:#ccc;
}

#button1 a, #button2 a {
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
}

#button1 a {
    background:url(http://lorempixum.com/40/40?1)
}

#button2 a {
    background:url(http://lorempixum.com/40/40?3)
}

#button1 a:hover, #button1.hover a {
    background:url(http://lorempixum.com/40/40?2)
}

#button2 a:hover, #button2.hover a {
    background:url(http://lorempixum.com/40/40?4)
}

#hidden1, #hidden2 {
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    border:4px solid #fcc;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var $buttons = $('div[id^=button]'),
    $hiddenDivs = $('div[id^=hidden]'),
    HOVER_CLASS = 'hover';

$buttons.live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        i = $this.index();

    $buttons.removeClass(HOVER_CLASS);
    $this.addClass(HOVER_CLASS);
    $hiddenDivs.hide().eq(i).show();
}).first().click();
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/VPYQX/)***

---

### Last edit

Changed JavaScript and CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/bNCNQ/

#### CSS

```
#button1:hover a, #button1.hover a {
    background:url(...)
}

#button2:hover a, #button2.hover a {
    background:url(...)
}
```

#### JS

```
$buttons.live('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        i = $this.index(),
        show = !$this.hasClass(HOVER_CLASS);

    $buttons.removeClass(HOVER_CLASS);
    $this.toggleClass(HOVER_CLASS, show);
    $hiddenDivs.hide().eq(i).toggle(show);
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you, sorry. My english is to sux. But the things I mentioned is the buttons image(normal and hover). When I click, active the hover corresponding button. Only img, not div background-color.

Comment: Oh yeah, you really understood what I looking for!

Comment: Only one thing to make it complete: I want to close/hide the showing divs if I click again.

Comment: Why don't you try to figure that bit out yourself, and come back if you run into problems?

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, but I'm very new to Javascript. I tried to make some changes:
I removed: .first (). click ();
And changed: .hide () to .hide(i)

It's almost working. Button2 working ok. Now only button1 not closing your corresponding hidden div.

Comment: Passing `i` into [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Ok, It's almost done. I changed to: $hiddenDivs.toggle().eq(i).hide();
But now showing "inverse" divs.
Button1 > Hidden2
Button2 > Hidden1

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. Sorry for asking so many questions and have put a code example so dirty. Really thanks Matt!

Comment: As long as you've learned something and can apply it in the future `:)`

Comment: Hey, I was trying to modify something, but getting another error now.
Look this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzcdv/81/)
This is working fine, but getting errors when I try to use these buttons divs inside other divs like this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzcdv/85/), they open only the same hidden div

Comment: @Alex: please try to go through the code and understand it. I know that you're new to jQuery but it's the tiniest of fixes. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/yWebL/

Comment: Whow, so sorry, by today I will start to study the main functions. But thank you again! God bless you for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R6vQ4/33/.

All of your JavaScript code can be condensed into this little block (and this isn't even as small as it can get):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('div[id^=button]').click(function()
{
  var element = $('#hidden' + $(this).attr('id').substr(6));
  $('div[id^=button]').css('cssText', 'background-color: none');

  if (element.is(':visible'))
  {
    $(this).css('cssText', 'background-color: none');
    $('div[id^=hidden]').hide();
  } else {
    $('div[id^=hidden]').hide();
    element.show();
    $(this).css('cssText', 'background-color: ' + $(this).css('background-color') + ' !important');
  }
});
});
```

The state of the button "sticks" when you press it, but my technique is a bit hacky, so feel free to change it.

When you use jQuery, you actually use it ;)

Comment: Thank you Blender. But it's opening the two divs. I want to show only one at a time.

Comment: And I want to stick the images hover into the divs when clicked. Not background-color. So thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I'm not going to do it *all* for you, so you're on your own now. I've modified it to work like you asked, so it won't be too hard to modify the example to work with images.

Comment: Sorry I don't want to be loose. It's because I have no knowledge of Javascript, I'm trying to start now. But thank you.

Comment: No problem. If you have more specific questions (like "Why doesn't this work"), they will get answered.